# Almost totally distinct functions

Tags: set-theory

Let us call $f,g:\omega\to \omega$ *almost totally distinct* if $$|\{n\in \omega: f(n) = g(n)\}| < \aleph_0.\;\;\;\; (\star)$$
It is known that there are uncountable collections of almost totally distinct functions.

**Question.** Is the above statement still true if we replace $\aleph_0$ by $2$ in $(\star)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. By pigeonhole principle any uncountable family of functions $f:\omega\to \omega$ contains two functions with the same pair $(f(1),f(2))$.

Comment: If this is so, why does the original statement hold (because the pigeonhole principle would say there is no uncountable family of almost totally distinct functions)?  Gerhard "Bewildered By Infinitely Many Pigeons" Paseman, 2017.02.22.

Comment: Ah. Even though I can find an uncountable family that agree on a given finite set, I can partition that family infinitely many times in a way agreeable to the definition of almost totally distinct. Once a finite bound on the size of the agreement set is put, I don't have the ability to split.  OK. Gerhard "Returning You To Regular Programming" Paseman, 2017.02.22.